# Ways to synchronize write access to a file on a network share

Tags: windows, networking, share, createfile, synchronize

I'm writing a program using C++ under Windows that needs to synchronize write access to a file via a local network. I was thinking to use the following approach:

```
//Create or open it using 0 for sharing mode
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(L"\\\\server\\share\\path\\file", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, , OPEN_ALWAYS, , ,);
if(hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE && ::GetLastError() == ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION)
{
    //Try again later
}
```

Can someone confirm that it's a workable solution?